# The type or namespace name 'WelcomeScreen' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a c# application and I am adding a new button.  When the button gets clicked I want to execute the following line:

```
WelcomeScreen channelBar = new WelcomeScreen(true, "http://www.trade-ideas.com/cms_static/ChannelBar/channelbar.html");
```

The problem is when I try to compile, I get the error message:

```
The type or namespace name 'WelcomeScreen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

WelcomeScreen is a class in a dll that I have referenced: TIProGUI.  Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: Likely missing a reference to `TIProGUI`. I.e. `using TIProGUI;`

Comment: Thanks.  I added the line: using TIProGUI; but still get  the same error message

Comment: Did you reference the library in your project? Try using the full path: `whatever.whatever.WelcomeScreen` when instantiating it. If it's an ambiguity issue this will most likely fix it.

Comment: Well it looks like you need to research what the namespace/class combination is. Without the source for `TIProGUI` you would have to contact the developer, find the API, or otherwise to find the namespace hierarchy. I.e. `TIProGUI.Classes.Something.WelcomeScreen`, or `TIProGUI.OtherThing.WelcomeScreen`. It could be anything, basically. I would start by finding the root namespace, then use Intellisense to go in from there.

Comment: I added "using TradeIdeas.TIProGUI;"  I also have a reference to it.  There is another dll that it successfully references "using TradeIdeas.TIProData;"

Comment: Thanks.  I will contact the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your "using" statements don't fully qualify the reference.  For example `System` and `System.Web.UI.WebControls` will have separate uses.

Comment: I got it to work by adding using TradeIdeas.TIProGUI; in the right place